# Crossfilter filterRange on dimension doens't work

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I have a list of cities with coords that I'm using with crossfilter library. I would like to filter a group of city in a defined longitude range. Do to that I use dimension.filterRange([min, max]) as described in wiki.

But it doesn't work. I've replied problem in JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wc8ba/256/

```
// raw_data contains list of citis with lat/lng info
var data = crossfilter(raw_data);

var lngDimension = data.dimension(function(d){return d.longitude;});
lngDimension.filterRange([0.37931289062498763, 11.805094140624988]);

// printFIlter is a useful function to show dimension data
printFilter(lngDimension);
```

In JSFiddle, you can see that "Sassari" city that has longitude = 8.56030000000 it is not included in filtered dimension with lng min = 0.37931289062498763 and max = 11.805094140624988

I would like to know why.

TIA 
Danilo Di Moia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not returning the right values as your longitude values are strings, not numbers.

If you use `var lngDimension = data.dimension(function(d){return parseInt(d.longitude);});` it should work correctly.

Comment: It works now... thanks a lot, jonowzz!

Instead, I was wondering why parseFloat(d.longitude) does not work...